# spamAssassin in plesk is not filtering spams

Tags: spamassassin

From couple of weeks ago, all our customers has start receiving spam emails. It seems like spamAssassin is not working as it should work. What could be the reasons?

Comment: is there any possibility that there might be something wrong with its rules file. because it is not picking up of some clear spam vulg* words (vi*gr*a). I have set the message filter level score 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate when I need to answer my own questions :)

I have added following server list in Plesk control panel -> Server -> Mail -> Preferences
Switch on spam protection based on DNS blackhole lists (DNS zones for DNSBL service)

abuse.rfc-ignorant.org;
zen.spamhaus.org;
cbl.abuseat.org;
bl.spamcop.net;
nomail.rhsbl.sorbs.net

and It is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to renew a licence from Plesk?

Comment: how I know about this? is there any way I know the status? Actually it is a managed dedicated server.